# Invalid PDF structure with Django and API REST

Tags: python, django, pdf, structure

I'm realizing a significiant project and I'm getting a problem without find a way to solve it.

I'm saving `pdf file` generated thanks to Django (`xhtml2pdf library`) to LogicalDoc. I create folder, .. but when I want to open the file, I'm getting the following error message :

```
Message : Invalid PDF structure
```

Strangely, It worked before and now it doesn't work. There is maybe an error with generated document, but I don't find where :

```
@login_required
def BirthCertificate_PDF(request, id) :

    birthcertificate = get_object_or_404(BirthCertificate, pk=id)

    data = {"birthcertificate" : birthcertificate}

    template = get_template('BC_raw.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))


    filename_directory = str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).id) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).lastname.encode('utf-8')) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).firstname.encode('utf-8')) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).birthday)
    filename = 'Acte_Naissance_' + filename_directory + '.pdf'
    path_individus = '/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Individus/'
    path = path_individus + filename

    print BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).folderId

    file = open(path, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')

    # If folderID is NULL : create a folder and save pdf file inside
    if BirthCertificate.objects.filter(pk=id).filter(folderId__isnull=True) :

        payload = '{{ "name":"{0}", "parentId":3309569 }}'.format(filename_directory)

        url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/folder/create'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
        resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
        rbody = resp.content
        data = json.loads(rbody)

        folderId_person = BirthCertificate.objects.filter(pk=id).update(folderId=data["id"]) # Give the number folderId to a person


        payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","folderId": "{1}" }}'.format(filename, BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).folderId) 
        upfile = path
        files = { 
        'document': (None, payload, 'application/json'),
        'content': (os.path.basename(upfile), open(upfile, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
        } 
        url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/document/create'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, auth=('admin', 'admin'))

        for element in glob.glob(path) :
            os.remove(element)

    #elif folderID is not null (corresponding to an existing folder), just save pdf file inside the folder. DON'T CREATE a new one.
    elif BirthCertificate.objects.filter(pk=id).exclude(folderId__isnull=True) :

        payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","folderId": "{1}" }}'.format(filename, BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).folderId)  
        upfile = path
        files = { 
        'document': (None, payload, 'application/json'),
        'content': (os.path.basename(upfile), open(upfile, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
        } 
        url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/document/create'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, auth=('admin', 'admin'))

        for element in glob.glob(path) :
            os.remove(element)



    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    context = {"birthcertificate":birthcertificate,
               "path":path,
    }

    return render(request, 'BC_PDF.html', context)

    file.close()

    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

I don't have errors in my terminal, but when I'm looking pdf file directly from LogicalDoc or when I download it from LogicalDoc :

[image]

Do you have any idea about my problem ? Something is wrong ?

**EDIT :**

When I'm opening my pdf file with a text editor, I'm getting :

```
%PDF-1.4
%ìåãû ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
1 0 obj
<< /F1 2 0 R /F2 3 0 R /F3 4 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /BaseFont /Courier-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F2 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /BaseFont /Courier /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F3 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >>
endobj
5 0 obj
<< /Contents 19 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.2756 841.8898 ] /Parent 18 0 R /Resources << /Font 1 0 R /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] >> /Rotate 0 /Trans <<  >> 
  /Type /Page >>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Outlines 8 0 R /PageMode /UseNone /Pages 18 0 R /Type /Catalog >>
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Author () /CreationDate (D:20170125090524+00'00') /Creator (\(unspecified\)) /Keywords () /ModDate (D:20170125090524+00'00') /Producer (pisa HTML to PDF <http://www.htmltopdf.org>) 
  /Subject () /Title () /Trapped /False >>
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Count 3 /First 9 0 R /Last 9 0 R /Type /Outlines >>
endobj
9 0 obj
<< /Count -1 /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /First 10 0 R /Last 10 0 R /Parent 8 0 R /Title (ACTE DE NAISSANCE COPIE INTEGRALE  ) >>
endobj
10 0 obj
<< /Count -7 /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /First 11 0 R /Last 17 0 R /Parent 9 0 R /Title (ACTE DE NAISSANCE COPIE INTEGRALE  ) >>
endobj
11 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Next 12 0 R /Parent 10 0 R /Title (ACTE DE NAISSANCE N\260 1 / 2017 Arnaud LOTUS ) >>
endobj
12 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Next 13 0 R /Parent 10 0 R /Prev 11 0 R /Title (Informations concernant l'enfant : ) >>
endobj
13 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Next 14 0 R /Parent 10 0 R /Prev 12 0 R /Title (Informations sur le p\350re : ) >>
endobj
14 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Next 15 0 R /Parent 10 0 R /Prev 13 0 R /Title (Informations sur la m\350re : ) >>
endobj
15 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Next 16 0 R /Parent 10 0 R /Prev 14 0 R /Title (Par la pr\351sente, l'officier d'Etat Civil certifie la conformit\351 de la d\351claration ) >>
endobj
16 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Next 17 0 R /Parent 10 0 R /Prev 15 0 R /Title (L'Officier d'Etat Civil  ) >>
endobj
17 0 obj
<< /Dest [ 5 0 R /Fit ] /Parent 10 0 R /Prev 16 0 R /Title (Signature et tampon  ) >>
endobj
18 0 obj
<< /Count 1 /Kids [ 5 0 R ] /Type /Pages >>
endobj
19 0 obj
<< /Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ] /Length 1351 >>
stream
Gb!;e?#u`2'RdI5s)?lTClKJ3K.l+Q6F'@s-;h&Z>J@>oACs5i!m]$9TA*b4\='"WSR'C$!i2=/\`]Q2)C]@pU#e17!F0kgISGAKn3We"#k02!HMu^XrSDt5V4/(@,$Yu%!7TrG'"WeWCDTeadd9'3\0_V'^=N&KG'"Z(UI84Kl/8[oBp<S->Bnk+!`aHK9O.gCIa-A^H!OO4eKB3lJTL(dE94sd):.Kko[<[<hHp9>045D4Wc>Y>CN+QG2g/Ulp"Z%)1T<!*PM-jT25qKNA/_%Ieg:G%_>Q.mpHQZLRDbbg^P)hG26N\RHGFD-+2J5h.X3@n\3Yc-o@9O2iU;4+NEt!>2k"4-D/T>/1n/0U/]u-OU"_\4KJk(^V@."73R1XI9lRDV?S>i.lTNJ8bT%\=@5;:M`nuS-[>B/;b(iHaCIE)O`bFXsP;(6^IM&DJ%RHNd'%'A[LsKTEWh%PBO><<P#"WNl>"%NgG"P1]OP),AD3R+aepf*#qGC:"-5JSL&r!g#1RP$i=N[1)YB+HgS`W`sW(u]6r;BEb\B>XmVb+I'%._Am4]JG5CCc?CLs\qO\9S+363\31BF)T4RlU(ugP=Gk%,p2e\h<oV2))UQ'@BOg9I,4@%Uc9O$0:Bt9VO#jG(gT@,@/)t\]1sq)YgRRO-+-u<F2gRjRScAl8Lp<eo>dg;lINgD)2O1@IBDB1.gu7hlCWR]BT'QEY!#LJYiQ]#S1C3^PT)>)u962r?bla&5.77dV)12@p=r<"OXg&"k@A]1j0"o*i:k4P6^PXp`3!Q.?5ds$T(g-<]?jc>3]n)l@eWl$#^9/Yjk3=jGHn%1[PdY"QA14"=e%^8qnEX77iOP>\?6D@U]+1hS,HbPBKqlY0p;a6uc2CiNH8Ye_!C5f!9C555Z#77iD3ip>G.H=#Hd[19_T4-IjpefjW!lhuq%*d8_3,^WERY(q%$Ji@.DeRHI[PMD-7l-]_h'MU86.2C="pHNj'``^Hbl3Bu>eponLI9Xr?'kU&l-2("nNRlRuud(*acqr6Q]B"XUj;S!KDfb+Xc3r4G)ABL1Ap4*u@Z+ERA-*_[>Cu#$_#hKqK]?,eWc&cm^G?$YH%>fIU,gV2jLG6`^P.([N)-rL;<@LjZlFCsm,!ou3@mi#ZY"D3:&TNa%1;_r&A&BjuZ&8OmfD<^)VXg^(k0D:&BN6qP'#FJOnQ?cb=JFHTQ=k*o(N:7?M.-a$<^^@q/fK>KZp>X.Wtl>u)Ed`";XodS6B(N%s).e"<8_;bs*l>^+I:$k%JSaRbiJ-a[3WC]]f+JnO$P@ed$#?DQ8VDVp)*Db&K@BhT.:9tr7+`Wo<,)OcRY%VrSDaXpd7[~>endstream
endobj
xref
0 20
0000000000 65535 f
0000000075 00000 n
0000000129 00000 n
0000000239 00000 n
0000000352 00000 n
0000000460 00000 n
0000000669 00000 n
0000000757 00000 n
0000001005 00000 n
0000001079 00000 n
0000001220 00000 n
0000001362 00000 n
0000001492 00000 n
0000001624 00000 n
0000001751 00000 n
0000001878 00000 n
0000002066 00000 n
0000002188 00000 n
0000002293 00000 n
0000002356 00000 n
trailer
<< /ID 
 % ReportLab generated PDF document -- digest (http://www.reportlab.com)
 [(Q:l\305\243:\334M\275B\203\250\311\260ug) (Q:l\305\243:\334M\275B\203\250\311\260ug)]
 /Info 7 0 R /Root 6 0 R /Size 20 >>
startxref
3804
%%EOF
```

Comment: Blind guess, the generated output contains some other data, try opening it with a text editor and see the head.

Comment: Which file exactly I have to open with a text editor ? My PDF file ?

Comment: Yes, the pdf file

Comment: The pdf file is correct, I see 2 `return` in your function. Probably there is something wrong here. Also you aren't closing your opened file (since the return trigger first) (prefer using `with` statement for files)

Comment: I understood my error ! I post my answer. It's because in a first time, I displayed pdf file directly in my django website. Then I modified my script in order to send pdf file to LogicalDoc without remove `return` wrote to display in Django website ...

Comment: Mind if i post my comment as an answer so you can close the thread by accepting it right now ?

Comment: yep if you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf file is correct (as shown by the correct start and end `%PDF-1.4 ... %%EOF` .
There is some errors in your code, I see 2 `return` statement in your function. Probably the result of some tests of refactoring.

Also, you aren't closing your opened file (since the return trigger first), prefer using `with` statement for files and let the file opened for the strict minimum of time (open, read, close), you have many things that have nothing to do with the file before reading it.

Finally, I advice running a `pep8` check over your code, you will see many errors that will be a problem soon or later (it would have yield the `return` problem immediatly).